# How to copy a javascript object with read-only members to non-read-only members?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript object, specifically a MouseEvent object:

```
    $('#my_container').bind('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (someCondition) {
        e.pageX = calcNewPageX
    }
}});
```

and I need to change the pageX property of this object, but it's readonly so I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property pageX of # which has only a getter

So I tried copying it to a new object and change the pageX property using jQuery's extend like this:

```
var copiedEvent = $.extend(true, { pageX: 500 }, e);
```

but I still get the same error.

How can I copy a MouseEvent object and set the pageX property of the new copy object to something of my own? What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: I need to pass this event object to a method (part of Highcharts framework, which I cannot change) which uses the pageX property on other charts to sync the crosshair position on each on of them.

Comment: Have you tried constructing a new MouseEvent with the values from the old event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: @PeteTNT yes, that actually worked, thanks!
I ended up doing something like this: `var copiedEvent = new Event(e); copiedEvent.pageX = newPageXValue` and got no console error.
If you add an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: added the answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a new event with `new Event` from your old event and modify those values:

```
var newEvent = new Event(e);
newEvent.pageX = calcNewPageX();
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events